# Как получить тексты постов Вконтакте и все комментарии к ним?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Не могу понять как сделать так чтобы в файл записало:

(текст 1го поста)
(комментарии к 1му посту)
(текст 2го поста)
(комментарии к 2му посту)

Окей, просто получить текста поста (а то и нескольких) легко get.wall-ом ( https://vk.com/pages?oid=-1&p=wall.get )

Просто получить текст комментов под постом тоже легко - в метод передал id поста и хорошо...

А если я хочу взять паблик, например https://vk.com/weeklyshonenjump и взять первые 20 постов и сразу комменты к ним то что делать ? Хорошо...20 раз "руками" вызвать метод скопировав id постов может и можно, а когда этих постов >100 то как-то не весело...существует ли подобный метод или надо всё делать как-то руками ?!

Comment: Вам `wall.get` возвращает `id` постов в том числе. Вы знаете, что по этому `id` можно получить комментарии. Так в чём проблема это запрограммировать? Я не понимаю суть Вашего вопроса, когда на нём метка [tag:python].

Comment: Я просто понятия не имею как это сделать (не руками), потому и спрашиваю =)

Comment: Решение на [tag:python] Вас устроит? Вы знаете этот ЯП? Сможете запустить код?

Comment: Да наверное смогу запустить, не то чтобы знал - я в компьютерах мало что смыслю но если это не использует какие-то сверх библиотеки (pip не работает использую загрузку библиотек через pycharm) то вполне должно включиться. А так питоном несколько лет пользуюсь наверное пойму

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если на записях не более сотни комментариев, то этот код подойдёт Вам:

```py
from vk_api import VkApi


def auth_handler():
    """Обработчик двухфакторной аутентификации (если включена)
    """
    key = input('Enter authentication code: ')
    return key, True


def main():
    vk_session = VkApi('login', 'password', auth_handler=auth_handler)
    vk_session.auth()
    vk = vk_session.get_api()

    posts = vk.wall.get(owner_id='-53753413', count=20)['items']
    posts_strings = [post['text'] for post in posts]

    comments_strings = []
    for post in posts:
        comments = vk.wall.getComments(owner_id='-53753413', post_id=post['id'], count=100)['items']
        comments_strings.append([comment['text'] for comment in comments])

    with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for p, c in zip(posts_strings, comments_strings):
            f.write(p + '\n')

            for x in c:
                f.write(x + '\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Спасибо, выручили =) Пришлось только, чутка  "подделать" сессию (у меня библиотека звалась просто `vk` и из нее нельзя было импортировать VkApi потому пришлось взять из своего старого кода авторизации кусок), и "поиграть" с командой sleep потомучто стала программа ругаться на частые запросы в цикле...впервые увидел такое