# Как получить тексты постов из группы ВК?

Tags: вконтакте

пробовал всё, что мог найти, не сработало

Comment: А что именно пробовали? Можно исправить сам вопрос, а то заминусуют...

Comment: Пробовал это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1064432/Как-получить-тексты-постов-Вконтакте-и-все-комментарии-к-ним и пытался сам как-то написать, не сработало